# How can I log packets dropped by policy in nftables?

Tags: linux-networking, nftables

I have a policy to drop packets in the input chain

```
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
```

How can I log just these dropped packets?

Comment: Have you checked http://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Logging_traffic

Comment: It's not helpful. I need to either log the policy or log everything and then disable logging for the accept rules.

Answer (score 5):

Well, I'm going to guess that you also want to know WHAT kind of packet is being logged at the end of your nftables chain.

Let us assume that you already have a log capture daemon (such as `syslogd`, `rsyslog-ng`, or `ulogd2`) that is already properly configured, daemonized, running, and reading all of your kernel loggings (from `/dev/log`) that is fed by kernel’s `ksyslog()` and saving these log messages to a file (such as `/var/log/message`).

## Your default policy is to ACCEPT

If your chain policy is to `accept`, then append the `log` keywords to your nftable rule:

```
table filter {
  ...
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
    ...
    # All my rules go here
    # Pick one that suits your needs best

    add rule inet filter input tcp dport 22 drop log
    add rule inet filter input tcp dport 21 counter drop log prefix my_input_ftp

  }
  ...
}
```

This will log any attempt at SSH or FTP to your SSH/FTP server then drop the packet.

## Your default policy is to DROP

I would add one line at the very end of that chain, example of `filter input` chain is given below:

```
table filter {
  ...
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
    ...
    # All my rules go here
    
    ...
    # Pick one that suits your needs best
    counter comment "total unfiltered input packets"
    log            # simple detail goes into the log
    log flags all  # extra details go into the log
    log flags all prefix "GOTCHA!: " # parseable keyword
    log flags all counter  # redundant but example
    # drop; # this is redundant policy is drop already
  }
  ...
}
```

Comment: These log command log everything not just the dropped/denied packets that the post asked about.

Comment: It seems we need ulogd2 [https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Logging_traffic] for reading wuch logs. In /var/log/messages I have no messages from nftables (Artix Linux)

Comment: @JohnEikenberry Maybe your comment was valid before an edit, but as I see it now: I don't think it logs everything. In the default ACCEPT section it only logs what is denied, and in de default DROP section it only get's to the end of the chain when the packet is not accepted before that. So, it only logs dropped packets in both examples.

Answer (score 2):

This work's for me:

```
log prefix "[nftables] Inbound Denied: " counter drop
```

Logs can be found:

```
/var/log/messages
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

The rules seem to be acted on in order. Policy is drop; then you have whatever accept rules you need. Now simply having

```
log
```

on a line by itself at the end does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Add 'log flags all log prefix "PREFIX " counter drop' as the last line in the input section of your ruleset. The packets that would normally be dropped by the default input policy drop will be logged and dropped by this ( the last ) rule. Yes it is redundant, however the redundancy is trivial.